# «С++ программист» или «программист С++»?

Tags: порядок-слов, информатика, стилистика

Как правильно указывать род деятельности программиста с привязкой к языку программирования?
Например, для подписи под текстом, письмом, отзывом, цитатой и т. д.

1. Иван Петров, С++ программист
2. Иван Петров, программист С++

Comment: Second variant are most popular on job sites.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я бы написал:

- Иван Петров, программист на С++
- Иван Петров, программист на Java и т.д.

Сравните:

- игра на пианино - пианист
- игра на гитаре - гитарист и т.д.

Но если специального слова нет, то:

- игра на бубне - игрок на бубне
- программирование на С++ - программист на С++

Comment: Специальное слово есть, "плюсовик". Но в официальных сообщениях я бы его не использовал.

Comment: Да, а также джавист, шарпист (C#), php-шник... но все неофициальные. Интересно, а есть уже названия профессий для JavaScript, Node.js, TypeScript, Go, Perl, Python, Ruby, Scala, Kotlin... ?

Comment: Конечно есть. Джаваскриптер, нодежээсник, тайпскриптер, гошник, питонщик, рубист. Про Perl, Scala и Kotlin ничего сказать не могу, но наверняка тоже как-то называют.

Comment: По этой логике, игрок на бубне - бубнист?

Answer (score 3):

Если выбирать из двух вариантов, я бы выбрал "С++ программист". Потому что "программист Java", "программист Python", "программист PHP" звучат коряво - они построены по аналогии с "программист ЭВМ", "администратор БД" но при этом наполнение у них совсем другое - ведь программист ЭВМ - это программист электронных вычислительных машин, а администратор БД - администратор баз данных.

Но я не стал бы выбирать из двух вариантов, второй очень корявый, первый - фактически калька с английского (С++ developer) - хоть и общепринятая.

Я бы написал:

- Иван Петров, программист (C++, Perl)
  или
- Иван Петров, программист на С++
  или
- Иван Петров, программист (специализация - С++)

Comment: По-моему, "программист Java" построен по модели "программист ЭВМ", "администратор БД" и т.п.

Comment: всё правильно, но программист ЭВМ - это программист электронных вычислительных машин, а администратор БД - это администратор баз данных.

Comment: А "Java-программист" я бы писал через дефис.

Comment: отредактирую ответ, потому что ваши примеры точнее

Comment: Отредактированный ответ гораздо лучше.

Comment: @SergeySlepov важное замечание сделал. Все привыкли калькировать с английского, но забывают, что в этом случае в русском языке нужно ставить дефис. Но «C++-программист» и выглядит, и звучит всё-таки коряво.

Comment: по-моему наиболее по-русски звучит предложенный вариант с предлогом `НА`

Comment: @shabunc, вам как модератору - мета: На этом сайте можно по-русски писать? Чем он тогда отличается от https://rus.stackexchange.com/? и куда лучше задавать такие вопросы? Спасибо.

Comment: на этом сайте можно писать на обоих языках,  самый честный ответ про то, почему есть russian и rus - это что второй был приобретён насколько я понимаю компанией когда russian уже существовал и развивался. Сейчас на rus пишут только по-русски, здесь можно на русском и на английском, но правилом хорошего тона считается ответить на том языке, на котором был задан вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Я программист, думаю некие мои мысли будут полезны.

Обычно, в названии языка программирования нет специальных знаков, кроме латинских букв, поэтому пишут и произносят через дефис.

- PHP-программист
- Ruby-программист

Часто говорят *разработчик* вместо *программист*.

Comment: Программисты С++ и C# c вашими утверждениями не согласны :)

Comment: Через дефис пишут совсем не поэтому. Дело в том, что в русском языке стоящее перед существительным слово, конкретизирующее его свойства (определение) согласовано с ним по роду и числу через окончание, и как часть речи это прилагательное. Если на это место ставится заимствованное слово без характерного для прилагательного окончания, то оно повисает в воздухе как чуждое русской грамматике. Дефис же позволяет составить новое слово, например, компакт-диск (в оригинале первая часть слова, compact - прилагательное, но без окончания прилагательного "компакт" перед существительным стоять не может).

Comment: @Alex_ander Поскольку абсолютное большинство слов, относящихся к компьютерам и программированию, заимствованное в русском языке, приходится мучаться :)